# Magento 2.4 Installation Issue

Tags: magento2.4

While installing magento2.4 using composer with php 7.4 I'm getting below message

> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.0].
> - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
> ```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

> ```
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
> - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
> ```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

How can I solve it.

Comment: check does this extension enable there or not? bcmath

Comment: @DhirenVasoya
In php.ini I could not find any extension like this. I am sharing you a file which are available on /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini

https://gofile.io/d/QGupXf

Comment: Then you need to install that one.

Comment: https://www.magecheckout.com/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-2-4-0-on-ubuntu-with-using-composer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the extension using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-bcmath
```

These are the extension, that required to do this :

```
ext-bcmath

ext-ctype

ext-curl

ext-dom

ext-gd

ext-hash

ext-iconv

ext-intl

ext-mbstring

ext-openssl

ext-pdo_mysql

ext-simplexml

ext-soap

ext-xsl

ext-zip
```

Comment: After installing this extension I did not require any other extension?

Comment: Check the above list, this is required to do installation. More information you can read this one : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: Thank you for your help
When I install any of the above. I'm getting error of https://ibb.co/PZ2XCCv

Comment: Your coomand need to like this one :  sudo apt-get install php7.4-ctype

Comment: If answer help then Upvote and accept as solutions, so it will help other in community.

Comment: actually the issue was different, my php 7.2 was enable so I have uninstall it and it solved my problem.

I have did it using sudo apt-get remove php7.2

Comment: I have upvoted and accept your answer :)